# How can I use URL parameters while debugging in Flash Builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-builder, url-parameters

How can I use URL parameters while debugging in Flash Builder 4?

Comment: Does this approach below work only with an http:// url (from an app server) or will it also work with a file:/// url from the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modify your html template**

In the "html-template" directory in your project open "index-template.html" up and modify the following lines of code to suite your needs:

```
var flashvars = {};
if (swfobject.getQueryParamValue("foo") && swfobject.getQueryParamValue("abc")) {
    flashvars.foo = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("foo");
    flashvars.abc = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("abc");
}
```

Please note that this is for a Flex 4 SDK project.

Further details may be found over here: [SWFObject docs](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.getQueryParamValue%28paramStr%29)

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the url that is used when FB launches the project for debugging in the project properties.  Just set your parameters there and them access them through the usual FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.